# Proper way to pass list to value_vars using pandas melt

Tags: python, pandas

I'm unsure how to do this with python but am stuck. The ticker values in the column are in a list format. When trying to pass that list to melt's value_vars I get an error. When I try converting to a tuple it still contains the list brackets. The documentation says "value_vars -- tuple, list, or ndarray, optional" -- not having success w/ list or tuple. Thanks in advance.

My data:

```
                    sector  ticker
0   Communication Services  [ATVI.OQ, GOOGL.OQ, GOOG.OQ, T.N, CTL.N, CHTR....
1   Consumer Discretionary  [AAP.N, AMZN.OQ, APTV.N, AZO.N, BBY.N, BKNG.OQ...
```

```
rowData = groups.loc[groups['sector'] == 'Communication Services']
print(tuple(rowData['ticker']))
new_df = pd.melt(new_df, id_vars=['date'], value_vars=rowData['ticker'])
```

The tuple doesn't look right with this output:

```
(['ATVI.OQ', 'GOOGL.OQ', 'GOOG.OQ', 'T.N', 'CTL.N', 'CHTR'],)
```

And here is the value_vars error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**EDIT**
Solved using

```
tup = tuple(rowData['ticker'].explode())
new_df = pd.melt(new_df, id_vars=['date'], value_vars=tup)
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing a nested list to `value_vars`. You will have to flatten it somehow. You might be able to use `value_vars=rowData['ticker'].values.flatten().tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data are not actually in wide format. I think what you want is just to explode the column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 'B': ['A', 'B']})
df.explode('A')
Out[21]: 
   A  B
0  1  A
0  2  A
0  3  A
1  4  B
1  5  B
1  6  B
```

But I'm not 100 per cent sure about what the end goal is. See http://xyproblem.info/.